# Cannot acquire DHCP address

Tags: networking, dhcp, ifconfig

I am unable to acquire a wired DHCP ip address.

I have Ubuntu 13.10 installed on a thin mini-itx ECS Q77H2-TI motherboard. I'm connecting to my cable modem which does provide ip addresses to other (windows, mac osx) machines I've connected to it.

When I run ifconfig I see:

```
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 74:27:ea:c2:62:58          
          inet6 addr: fe80::7627:eaff:fec2:6258/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:267 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:516 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:50017 (50.0 KB)  TX bytes:111906 (111.9 KB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f7c00000-f7c20000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1624 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0          
          TX packets:1624 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0    
          RX bytes:132240 (132.2 KB)  TX bytes:132240 (132.2 KB)
```

cat /etc/network/interfaces gives:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

When I try tcpdump -i eth0 -n, I see nothing, but tcpdump -i eth1 -n, I see plenty of activity when wired.

I would love some pointers on how to get this machine connected to the internet.

Cheers,

Owen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your pc view only eth1 interface. Ifconfig don't see eth0.
You can try with nm-tool command to see nic card, state ...
Simple output will be like this

```
$ nm-tool
NetworkManager Tool
State: connected
- Device: eth0  [Auto eth1] ----------------------------------------------------
 Type:              Wired
 Driver:            xxxxx
 State:             connected
 Default:           yes
 HW Address:        74:27:ea:c2:62:58
 Capabilities:
 Carrier Detect:  yes
 Speed:           100 Mb/s
 Wired Properties
 Carrier:         on
 IPv4 Settings:
 Address:         xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
 Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
 Gateway:         xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
 DNS:             xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
 DNS:             xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Also you can try to renew ip settings from dhcp server
first

```
ifconfig eth1 down
```

next

```
ifconfig eth1 up
```

or

```
dhclient eth1
```

You will probably get ip from dhcp ...

If is your cable in eth0 interface try to up interface

```
ifconfig eth0 up
```

Comment: These are really great tips. I would upvote but I've only just joined askubuntu.

Comment: Your problem is fixed and this is enough. Happy hacking :)

Answer (score 4):

To answer my own question,

1. I added a dhcp entry to /etc/network/interfaces

   ```
   auto eth1
   iface eth1 inet dhcp
   ```
2. I then restarted my cable modem. The modem appears to only provide one DHCP ip address per power cycle.

Fixed.

Comment: You saved my day.