# My Wired connection (ethernet) on a fresh Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS install doesn't work, what's wrong?

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, ethernet

I'm using a laptop at home and it seems there is problem I can't use my wired connection.
I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (kernel version 5.3.0-40-generic).

On my wife's PC there is also Ubuntu 18.04 and it works fine: she is connected with wire too.

My network adapter doesn't get an ip address:

```
enp0s31f6: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether 50:7b:9d:f9:b2:e8  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    device interrupt 16  memory 0xf1400000-f1420000
```

I have run the command

```
sudo dhclient -v enp0s31f6


Listening on LPF/enp0s31f6/50:7b:9d:f9:b2:e8
Sending on   LPF/enp0s31f6/50:7b:9d:f9:b2:e8
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s31f6 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x4007ea6f)
```

and it got stuck! on the **DHCP discover**!
So it seems my Wired network adapter fails. I think it comes from the driver.
I have checked with:

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

The output is (the virtual network devices were filtered):

```
  *-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   logical name: wlp1s0
   version: 20
   serial: c8:ff:28:6a:4e:61
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=5.3.0-40-generic firmware=SW_RM.1.1.1-00157-QCARMSWPZ-1 ip=192.168.1.4 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:131 memory:f1000000-f11fffff

  *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: Ethernet Connection I219-V
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 1f.6
   bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
   logical name: enp0s31f6
   version: 21
   serial: 50:7b:9d:f9:b2:e8
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.13-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
   resources: irq:128 memory:f1400000-f141ffff
```

The output of the command:

```
sudo journalctl -b 0 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager


Mar 06 08:58:06 speedtLaptop NetworkManager[629]: <info>  [1583477886.0632] init!
Mar 06 08:58:06 speedtLaptop NetworkManager[629]: <info>  [1583477886.0817]       interface-parser: parsing file /etc/network/interfaces
Mar 06 08:58:06 speedtLaptop NetworkManager[629]: <info>  [1583477886.0818]       interface-parser: finished parsing file /etc/network/interfaces
Mar 06 08:58:06 speedtLaptop NetworkManager[629]: <info>  [1583477886.0818] management mode: unmanaged
Mar 06 08:58:06 speedtLaptop NetworkManager[629]: <info>  [1583477886.0823] devices added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.6/net/enp0s31f6, iface: enp0s31f6)
Mar 06 08:58:06 speedtLaptop NetworkManager[629]: <info>  [1583477886.0823] device added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.6/net/enp0s31f6, iface: enp0s31f6): no ifupdown configuration found.
Mar 06 08:58:06 speedtLaptop NetworkManager[629]: <info>  [1583477886.0823] devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/lo, iface: lo)
Mar 06 08:58:06 speedtLaptop NetworkManager[629]: <info>  [1583477886.0823] device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/lo, iface: lo): no ifupdown configuration found.
Mar 06 08:58:06 speedtLaptop NetworkManager[629]: <info>  [1583477886.0823] end _init.
```

Since the file: `/etc/network/interfaces` content was **only**:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

I have added the two lines:

```
auto enp0s31f6
iface enp0s31f6 inet dhcp
```

But it seems when I enter the command:

```
sudo ifup enp0s31f6
```

it seems to be stuck on DHCPDISCOVER forever.

The same issue when I run the command:

```
sudo dhclient -v enp0s31f6
```

What's wrong? Why don't I receive an IP from my home router when it comes to a wired connection??

Does someone perhaps has a suggestion?

Comment: Click on the network connection symbol on the top bar. Does it show Wired Connected there?

Comment: restart your router and try again https://askubuntu.com/a/435509/925971

Comment: @Graham there is no wired connection. i have no ip address for my interface.

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the bits you added to `/etc/network/interfaces`: Ubuntu 18.04 uses [Netplan](https://netplan.io/) instead of `ifupdown`, and in any case, you should have NetworkManager handling your wired and wireless connections. There is no need for you to enter things manually through the config files in `/etc/`.

Have you tried using `nmtui` (a NetworkManager user interface) to make sure the interface is on, and configured to use DHCP?

Also, it wouldn't hurt to add the output of `ip addr`.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion but  when i try to activate I get:
"Could not activate connection: Connection "Wired Connection 1 " is not available on the device enp0s31f6 at this time.